# Create different segues from one tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I created a menu inside of my app.

The menu has 4 cells, which are created by modifying a prototype cell.

Each of those cells should perform a segue to one of 4 `ViewController`s.

How can I realize this? Any ideas?

Comment: This is quite easy. All you need to do is create segues to your destination view controllers from the source view controller. When user taps a cell you should call the `performSegueWithIdentifier:` method in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

1) Create 4 prototype cells having each one wired directly to its respective viewController.  In this case, each give each prototype cell its own identifier (for example `"cell1"`, `"cell2"`, `"cell3"` and `"cell4"`) and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dequeue using the appropriate identifier for the row: `["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"][indexPath.row]`.

OR

2) Wire the segues from the viewController icon at the top of your viewController, give the segues identifiers, and trigger the appropriate segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

[image: wiring segue from VC]